# How to wait for shell command to fully open application?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, my VBA code is able to verify if a file exists or not. If it exists, it opens the file and replaces all instances of "Test" with "Hello". If it does not exist, it sends a message stating so. My problem is that upon opening the file (*in this instance a Word document*), it may take several seconds and the code returns a "run-time error". Is there a way I can wait for the application to fully open until proceeding? I have tried the "Application.Wait" method, but it is not so reliable, since the file may take more than a second. Additionally, I have seen other forums suggest using WScript.Shell instead, but is there a way I can use the type in my code?

```
If strFileExists = "" Then
    MsgBox "The selected file doesn't exist"
Else
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    objShell.ShellExecute strFileName, "", "", "open", 3
        
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
        myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Test", ReplaceWith:="Hello", _
        Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Set objShell = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: VBA doesn't know what `ActiveDocument` is.  If you want to work with Word documents then create an instance of Word and open the document in that.  Plenty of examples to be had googling for "VBA automate Word"

Comment: @Tim Williams I did see that was an option, but in this instance I’m using the shell command because I only have the file name and not the entire file path. The program successfully opens my file, but it’s not always a Word document. Would there be a way I could substitute the application.wait line of code to wait for the file to open?

Comment: Even if you wait (and you can simulate that just by adding a breakpoint in your code) I'm pretty sure this won't work.  As noted above, this will not create an `ActiveDocument` object for you to work with.

Comment: @Tim Williams Interesting, I am still able to open the file and run the code to replace all instances of “Test” with “Hello” if I wait long enough. So there is no way I can check to see that the file was opened fully?

Comment: @Samuel if the shell waits until the document is open to end, you can write in your shell script that it creates a txt on a fixed path and make your excel look for that txt, waiting until it's created.

Comment: Seems like there's some relevant code you're not showing us.

Comment: So, do you only have the file name, but not the folder where it exists?

Comment: @FaneDuru I do have the folder name. But, in this example, I'm trying to see what I can do with the file name itself.

Comment: I cannot imagine the reason, but probably my imagination has some limitations... Since, you ca easily open it in an existing, or in a new created session, your way of trying looks a little strange to me. Anyhow, even if opening it in your way, you can easily find the Word open session, then iterate between all open document in a loop, until the workbook in discussion name/full name is the one you are looking for... If it looks complicated, I can show you how it can be done. But in comment the code will not be understandable enough, I am afraid... `GetObject` may also work, I think.

Comment: Please update your question with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows API [FindWindowExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa) or [FindWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) functions to solve your problem (I suppose you're using Windows). BTW, I've implemented API solution for the same problem at my work (cannot provide the code, as I am not at my work desktop and on Linux, ATM).

Find what the window title is (just open the file and type the title you see in the title bar). Usually, it consists of a file name and the name of the application (e.g., `my_file.docx - Word` or `my_file - Word`). Then, put `FindWindowExA` or `FindWindowA` function into `While` or `Until` loop. Pass the window title to the function. Once, the window with the specified title is found, exit the loop.

Comment: Should help be needed, let me know. I'll try to share my work solution (when will be at work).